# Why do bootloaders get installed on different harddrives?

Tags: ubuntu, bootloader

When I install an operating system to my system, I've learned to disconnect all drives other than my target drive because the bootloader tends to sort of just... land wherever the hell it wants.

The last time I remember being bit by this was installing Windows 8 back in 2014, but just yesterday the same thing happened when installing Ubuntu. I told the Ubuntu installer to target a Samsung SSD, only to see a boot entry created for Ubuntu on my Windows NVME drive. This means the target drive cannot boot the OS on its own, and there now exists a needless, unexpected, and astonishing dependency on a different drive in the system. This is obviously undesirable behavior because I can't boot using the drive I just installed the OS to unless I reconnect a drive that shouldn't have been modified in the first place.

Why do bootloaders, in general, do this during OS installation? This is especially astonishing behavior considering OS installation wizards explicitly ask which drive the OS should be on, and then the bootloader just... doesn't go there??

Comment: its a common firmware fallback to look at the first disk on the first controller for the bootloader. Note that from the motherboard manufacturer's perspective, there can only be one boot loader. a Multiboot system should have exactly 1 bootloader that is configured to work for all the OSes installed. its common for instance in linux/windows dual boots to put grub on the disk with the boot loader, and have it boot whichever OS is desired. it is not really expected to make the user hit F8 or F12 in the firmware load phase of boot to select a boot volume.

Comment: Slight rant here; I'm perplexed that installers don't even have an option for "Force install of bootloader on same drive". When I install an OS to a drive, I expect that drive will be single-handedly capable of bringing up a system. If its bootloader ends up on a different drive then that expectation will not be met. Thanks for your information

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with UEFI implementation.

Even though the [EFI specification](https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI_Spec_2_9_2021_03_18.pdf) does not impose a restriction on number of EFI/system partitions or their locations (specified under section 13.3.3 and 13.3.4.3), ideally there should exist only one EFI partition per system. Or at least that's what most distro installers follow. Even Windows doesn't create a new partition on a clean install if a EFI partition already exists.

A solution is to manually create a separate EFI partition and then installing the bootloader there. I don't know the exact steps on Ubuntu's installer. However, I have done this on Calameres by choosing `Manual Partitioning` and setting the EFI/Boot flags on the newly created partition.

PS: Based on some reading, I guess the restriction on number of partitions was imposed in an older spec and now it is just a matter of ensuring backwards compatibility.

Comment: That is insightful, but can you cite your statement about "Even Windows doesn't create a new partition on a clean install if a EFI partition already exists"?Is that in a document somewhere detailing the behavior of the installer?

Comment: @DeepDeadpool I don't have a link to a official doc, however it can be seen mentioned on the [ArchWiki here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dual_boot_with_Windows#The_EFI_system_partition_created_by_Windows_Setup_is_too_small) as well as several random posts on StackExchange sites. I have myself used this behavior to have a larger EFI partition.